# Meteor.js: How to periodically query collection documents from view

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I have a view that I want to be essentially a dynamic slideshow:

1. load a view
2. start a timer so that every X seconds a random document from a particular collection is returned (typical `collection.findOne()` request)
3. when that item is loaded, trigger a function with the data attached

this sounds like it could be a typical jquery _GET request, but it would be good to know the 'meteor' way of doing it.

Here is essentially a starting point of what I'd like to do:

```js
// week_player.js


var randomWeekInterval;

// triggered when page is first loaded
Template.weekPlayer.rendered = function(){
    console.log('rendered!');
    var tick = 0;
    randomWeekInterval = Meteor.setInterval(function(){

        console.log('week interval update ' + (tick++));

        var weekCount = Weeks.find().count();
        var randomWeekId = Math.floor(weekCount * Math.random());

        var randomWeek = Weeks.findOne(randomWeekId);

        // TODO: add some sort of listener for when the week is loaded
        // and trigger newDataHandler with the data

    }, 10 * 1000); // repeat every 10 seconds
}

// triggered when the new data is loaded
Template.weekPlayer.newDataHandler = function(data){
    // got new data! here it is:
    console.log(data);
}

// triggered when leaving page: stop doing the interval
Template.postPage.destroyed = function(){
    Meteor.clearInterval(randomWeekInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
_.extend(Template.weekPlayer, {
  created: function() {
    this.randomWeekInterval = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
      Session.set("randomWeekIndex", Math.floor(Weeks.find().count() * Math.random()));
    }, 10 * 1000);
  },

  destroyed: function() {
    Meteor.clearInterval(this.randomWeekInterval);
  },

  week: function() {
    return Weeks.findOne({}, {
      skip: Session.get("randomWeekIndex"),
      transform: function(doc) {
        // Here's where you can manipulate the object after it is retrieved

        return doc;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Now you can get the week object directly from your template and it will automatically change to the new week whenever the `Session` var is changed:

```html
<template name="weekPlayer">
  {{#with week}}
    Start Date: {{startDate}} <br/>
    End Date: {{endDate}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

A few notes:

- The interval is set in the `created` callback, rather than the `rendered`. This is to ensure that there will always be only one `setInterval` for each `clearInterval`. If it's in the `rendered` callback a new interval will be set every single time the template is rendered, which could be hundreds of times. You also lose your references to your interval objects.
- Because we reference the interval on `this` inside the `created` and `destroyed` callbacks, you can have multiple slideshows, each with their own interval objects.
- We use `Session` to store the random index. The template helper function `Template.weekPlayer.week` will automatically be re-run every time that `Session.set("randomWeekIndex", "someValue")` is run. Then, the template will be automatically re-rendered because it depends on the `week` helper.
- The HTML portion assumes that your `week` objects have `startDate` and `endDate` fields. They could of course follow any structure, and the `transform` option allows you to modify their structure however you need to before displaying them. If the objects are fine as they are, you can remove the `transform` option from the `findOne` call.
- I'm using Underscore's `_.extend` for conciseness. If you haven't seen this before, it's the same as saying:

  ```
  Template.weekPlayer.created = function() { /* ... */ };
  Template.weekPlayer.destroyed = function() { /* ... */ };
  // ...
  ```

A final note - you should find yourself very rarely using jQuery when using Meteor. Whenever you need to talk to the Meteor server you want to use Meteor methods instead of jQuery AJAX. Whenever you need to get data from the server you'll want to use publications/subscriptions. Whenever you want to do basic DOM manipulation, you'll let templates and reactive helper functions (e.g. `Template.weekPlayer.week`) do it for you as I've shown here.

Comment: thanks! the transform callback function was key. I'm surprised there isnt a more graceful way of handling that event before sending it off to the handlebars template.

Comment: You can also provide a transform function when you define the collection itself, such as `new Meteor.Collection("weeks", {transform: function() { /* ... */ }});` - not really sure how it could be more graceful, seems like its far fewer lines of code than alternative frameworks.

Comment: It sounds from your description that the transform function probably isn't completely necessary - you can probably achieve the same thing with some template helpers. Either way, what I like about Meteor is how declarative its API is, as opposed to having to implement an imperative solution as described in your OP

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are reactive. You could use a template helper on the weekPlayer template that returns the Session object

**Template Helper**

```
Template.weekPlayer.helpers({
    currentSlide: function(){
        return Session.get('currentSlide');
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<template name="weekPlayer">
    {{currentSlide}}
</template>
```

**Periodic Updates**

```
var tick = 0;
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    // update contents of slide data
    tick += 1;
    // set currentSlide Session object -- which triggers a redraw
    Session.set('currentSlide', tick);
}, 1000);
```

Now a note on this, you might want to take the **Meteor.setInterval** call and move it outside of the **Template.weekPlayer.rendered** function. That way you're not creating a new Meteor.setInterval every time your redraw (or using Meteor.clearInterval -- just some mechanism to keep from call Session.set unexpectedly)